# Sqlite Update query using a subquery

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have to update table test_test column `"testconsent_id"` with the id value of table `test_groupedconsent,` where the `patient_id` in `test_test` and `patient_id` in `test_groupedconsent` table match and
also creation_date in both table match.
I'm using the below query but getting error -- `"near "as": syntax error".`

what is wrong with the query?

```
Update test_test as Tinner join (select id,patient_id,creation_date from test_groupedconsent) as Aon A.patient_id = T.patient_id and A.creation_date = T.creation_dateset T.testconsent_id = A.id;
```

Answer (score 15):

You cannot use a join directly in an UPDATE statement.

You have to use a correlated subquery to look up the desired value (in the subquery, you can do whatever you want, but in this case, you don't even need a join):

```
UPDATE test_test
SET testconsent_id = (SELECT id
                      FROM test_groupedconsent
                      WHERE patient_id    = test_test.patient_id
                        AND creation_date = test_test.creation_date);
```

Comment: I ran `UPDATE moz_bookmarks SET dateAdded = (SELECT dateAdded FROM places_backup.moz_bookmarks WHERE guid = moz_bookmarks.guid);` and it reset the `dateAdded` value to be the same for all rows.

Comment: this is missing a "where" clause on the update, and so is the lower answer.

Answer (score 0):

sounds like it took the 'as' after join for the joined tables so either put as in the (... as ...) or bring "ON COMMAND" before as!
like this -> (table1 join table2 on table1.fiel = table2.field) as something

Answer (score -1):

```
UPDATE TABLE test_test 
SET testconsent_id = 
   (SELECT testconsent_id FROM test_groupedconsent AS A, test_test AS B 
    WHERE A.patient_id = B.patient_id AND A.creation_date = B.A.creation_date)
```

Comment: I tried the query but this is making testconsent_id="1" for all the entries.